# How to add external messaging broker to Wildfly?

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, apollo

I'm using WildFly to deploy an EJB war that use an external messaging broker (i.e. Apollo) not the the one that come with WildFly (i.e. ActiveMQ Artemis).

What must I do to setup a JNDI configuration in `standalone-full.xml` file? There isn't any helpful tutorial to do this, and I don't know what exactly I need to change in the configuration to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Is this post any help?
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Connect+a+pooled-connection-factory+to+a+Remote+Artemis+Server

I was able to use an external artermis broker (not the Wildfly container) following the above example.